# Likelihood function takes extremely small values

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to marginalize the likelihood function (with Gaussian noise) with respect to one parameter in Wolfram Mathematica. It takes extremely small values (like Exp[-2500] or so) and consequently Wolfram returns exact zero. After this marginalization, I have to minimize -Log of likelihood and then everything becomes finite. Can you suggest the ways how to overcome this marginalization step problem in Wolfram? Thank you!

```
Data = {{m -> 0.014, x -> 14.42, dy -> 0.23}, {m -> 0.016, 
    x -> 15.65, dy -> 0.22}, {m -> 0.016, x -> 15.37, dy -> 0.3}};

d[Om_?NumberQ, Oa_?NumberQ, Ho_?NumberQ, 
  m_?NumberQ] := (1 + m)*((2.9*10^5)/Ho)*
  NIntegrate[Re[1/(Om*(1 + z)^3 + Oa)^(1/2)], {z, 0, m}, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

fun[Om_?NumberQ, Oa_?NumberQ, Ho_?NumberQ, m_?NumberQ] := 
 5*(Log[10, d[Om, Oa, Ho, m]] - 1)

logLikelihood[Om_?NumberQ, Oa_?NumberQ, Ho_?NumberQ, M_?NumberQ] := 
 Sum[(-1/2)*(((x - fun[Om, Oa, Ho, m] - M)^2/(dy^2))) /. 
   Data[[i]], {i, 1, 3}]

marginalized[Om_?NumberQ, Oa_?NumberQ, Ho_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[logLikelihood[Om, Oa, Ho, M]], {M, -20, -18}, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

marginalized[1, 0, 70]
```

This is a simplified version of what I am doing but generates same error.

Comment: I am guessing that you have decimal floating point numbers somewhere in your calculation. Those will behave as you describe. If you only have exact rational numbers then `Log[Exp[-2500]]` returns exactly `-2500`

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful for you. Compare `Log[Exp[-2500.0105478]]` which returns a warning and `Indeterminate` versus `N[Log[Exp[Rationalize[-2500.0105478,0]]],12]` which returns no warning and `-2500.01054780` So perhaps you can insert `Rationalize[...,0]` in appropriate places in your code and get the results that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still getting NIntegrate::izero error, I tried changing minrecursion option but it does not help.

Comment: If you can edit your post to show a small example that produces the error then I can see if I can find a solution.

Comment: I do not know if it is feasible or not. Can you try this change `marginalized[Om_?NumberQ,Oa_?NumberQ,Ho_?NumberQ]:=Integrate[Exp[Rationalize[logLikelihood[Om,Oa,Ho,M],0]],{M,-20,-18}]` and wait long enough to see if that will complete? Using `NIntegrate` in that step will force everything back to floating point which will fail.